# junit tests to check creation of a file

Tags: java, junit4, mule

If you have a loop which is creating text files every 5 seconds and names it after the timestamp it was created, can you create a junit test, to see if it was created? how would you check?

thanks for your help

Comment: I'd mock the object used to actually create the file, and verify if the creation functions have been called with the right arguments. IMHO it is not a Unit test anymore, if you actually have to verify files created in the file system...

Answer (score 1):

I would mock the creation using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). And check if the create method is called and which file name is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check that the file exists, but this is more integration testing than unit testing.

The recommended approach would be to create some sort of `FileCreator` interface like so

```
public interface FileCreator {
    void createFile(Date date);
}
```

Create your implementation that formats the time and then unit test  - verify that when you call `createFile` your file is really created. This should be simple.

Now, use that in your class that creates files - lets assume it looks like this

```
public class FileCreationManager {

    private final FileCreator fileCreator;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private Future<?> taskHandle;

    public FileCreationManager(final FileCreator fileCreator) {
        this.fileCreator = fileCreator;
    }

    public void startFileCreation() {
        taskHandle = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fileCreator.createFile(new Date());
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void stopFileCreation() {
        taskHandle.cancel(false);
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Your unit test you can pass in a dummy implementation of the `FileCreator` and you only have to check that `createFile` is called with the right `Date`.

You could run the creation thread for a few seconds and collect the `Date`s passed in into a `Collection` - your unit next now needs to check that the `Date`s are 5 seconds apart and that there is the right number of them.